# Mapping ef model to dto with AutoMapper, exception thrown for DateTime datatype

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, automapper

I am making Web Api + Entity Framework app. So I am using `AutoMapper` to map EF model class to DTO class.

This is configuration for `AutoMapper` important one is `Apartment`. This method is called in `Global.asx` file

```
public class AutoMapperConfiguration
{
    public static void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg => 
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<Amenities, AmenitiesDTO>();
            cfg.CreateMap<Image, ImageDTO>();
            cfg.CreateMap<Location, LocationDTO>();
            cfg.CreateMap<Comment, CommentDTO>();
            cfg.CreateMap<Reservation, ReservationDTO>();
            cfg.CreateMap<Apartment, ApartmentDTO>();
        });
    }
}
```

This is problematic property in `ApartmentDTO` class.

```
public List<DateTime> FreeDate { get; set; }
```

This is problematic property in `Apartment` class.

```
[Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
public List<DateTime> FreeDate { get => freeDate; set => freeDate = value; }
```

This is controller action that I'm targeting with Postman.

```
public IQueryable<ApartmentDTO> GetApartments()
{
    var apartments = db.Apartments
        .Include(a => a.Amenities)
        .Include(a => a.Images)
        .Include(a => a.Location)
        .Include(a => a.Reservations.Select(c => c.Comment)).ProjectTo<ApartmentDTO>();


    return apartments;
}
```

And I get the following error:

```
The specified type member 'FreeDate' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.
```

So I need to do something with `DateTime` data type so it can be used with DTO and get working response in Postman. What?

Edit: I`m guessing that problem has something to do with `List<DateTime>`, because i had exact same setup with `DateTime` in `ReservationsController` and it worked fine.

Comment: How exactly do you see the mapping of a sql `datetime2` to a c# `List<DateTime>` happening?

Comment: @SamAxe I don't know. Could you please elaborate, how exactly is your question contributing to answering mine? For now i know that sql `datetime2` will map to `DateTime` c#. So it means i don't know to make sql list `datetime2`?

Comment: @SamAxe well it contributed, in a way that i learnt that i can`t store lists in an sql database. So to store a list of dates i need to make it a csv string of dates or something like that, right? Thanks

Comment: That architecture depends on how you are going to use the data.  If you don't need to query it.. (eg, it is *purely* for display purposes) then store it however makes sense for your display technology.  But if you need to query those dates, or compare them, or format them, or anything else - then they need to be in a form that is conducive to those operations.  That *usually* means a new table on the many side of a one-to-many relationship with your primary data.   But if you don't already know that I would highly recommend a get a book or class to teach you proper data modeling.

Comment: @SamAxe thank you, will do